# LDAP_BIND Can't contact LDAP server

Tags: php, ldap

I have a question for you.

My goal is to bind a ldap server with php.

- When I try with a terminal ( bash ) I use:

> ldapsearch -H ldaps://[server]:[port] -D [dn] -W

It works well.

- When I try with a php script

> $server = array("ldaps://[server]", "[port]");
>
> $userdn = "[dn]";
>
> $userpw = "[pw]";
>
> $ds = ldap_connect($server[0], $server[1]) or die("ldap server offline");
>
> ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
>
> ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
>
> ldap_bind($ds, $userdn, $userpw);

Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

I don't understand my mistake. I've search all night long on google.

Q/A

> _ I use mamp ( apache )
>
> _ Ldap server pings good, and works with bash.
>
> _ I use a firewall, but it doesnt work without too.
>
> _ all [var] are ok, because in bash it works.

Comment: you should try using the bit about LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE on the ldap_bind man page at php.net to get a more verbose fail message.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php

Comment: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain)

Comment: adding TLS_REQCERT allow to ldap.conf and it works! thanks you mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `TLS_REQCERT allow` to ldap.conf and it works! thanks to @rooster

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to disable the certification check via PHP. *But keep in mind that this is a security risk if the connection is routed over a public network!*

```php
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_ALLOW);
```

Consult https://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.constants.php to find the documentation of other options (`LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_HARD, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_TRY`).

For some people this may be preferable over modifying the `ldap.conf`.